# How to give permissions to all workflow subsites created from a site template?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, app-permissions

I have a site with a workflow, that need some permissions to perform some actions. I put the required permissions using de url _layouts/15/appinv.aspx and save this site as template. However and i create another site based from that template i always have to give the permissions to the workflow manualy again.

Someone know a way to create this new sites with the necessary permissions to the workflow already? I dont want to put this permissions every time i create a site.

Comment: Have you tried to apply wider permissions scope for the workflow and request permissions to all site collections in the tenant? I mean something like `<AppPermissionRequests>
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Write"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>`

Comment: The problem it is that every site i create generate another workflow  app to that site. I dont think this would work.